# Twitter bootstrap modal not showing correct image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, href

I'm having trouble with displaying the modal for the specific image clicked on to view.

If i use a link with a class it will show all of the images in that album in seperate modals (have to close them all down). I want to show the appropriate modal for the image that I click "view" on so that it is corresponding.

If i set this to id and create an id in the top div it will display the first image in the album only, no matter what image i click on.

How could I solve this?

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href=".modal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i>     View</a>

<!--POP OVER OF IMAGE-->
<div class="modal hide fade"  tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Pansnap</h3>

</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<!--This is for the 360 viewer-->

<?php echo '<img src="uploads/', $image["album"], '/', $image["id"], '.',     $image["ext"],'"/>'?>

<!--360 viewer end-->

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
 <?php echo '<a class="btn btn-link" href="uploads/', $image["album"], '/', $image["id"],     '.', $image["ext"],'">Download</a>'?>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't have more than one <a> or <img> so it's hard to say, but my first guess would be that you need to make each ID name unique. Could you provide more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to store the various unique data components on each of the links and then have a generic handler which will load that data into the relevant elements of a single modal.

For instance, something along the lines of:

### HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href="#imageModal" data-toggle="modal" data-image="uploads/album/01.jpg" data-download="uploads/album/01.jpg"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i>     View</a>
<a class="btn btn-link" href="#imageModal" data-toggle="modal" data-image="uploads/album/02.jpg" data-download="uploads/album/02.jpg"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i>     View</a>

<!--POP OVER OF IMAGE-->
<div id="imageModal" class="modal hide fade"  tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Pansnap</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <img id="snap"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <a id="download" class="btn btn-link">Download</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where you could load each image's data into the data attributes via PHP.

### JS

```
$(document).on('click.modal.image-data', '[href=#imageModal]', function () {
  $('#snap').attr('src',$(this).data('image'))
  $('#download').attr('href', $(this).data('download'))  
})
```

This will load the appropriate data in the modal elements.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/VXkJv/)